# total of sales for each item in different columns with specific year

Tags: sql

### 1. This is the normal code

```
SELECT A.customer_id,

        SUM(B.quantity*b.list_price) AS [ITEM SALES]

     -- ,

     --(SELECT SUM(quantity*list_price)

     -- FROM sales.order_items

     -- WHERE YEAR(order_date) = '2016') AS [TOTAL SALES 2016]

FROM sales.orders AS A

RIGHT JOIN sales.order_items AS B

ON A.order_id = B.order_id      

GROUP BY A.customer_id

ORDER BY A.customer_id ASC
```

---

RESULT // I need to display the TOTAL OF SALES IN 2016

```
1   30645.87
2   21653.85
3   26249.81
4   24198.88
5   19442.88
6   35857.86
7   7707.96
8   2603.95
9   26679.78
```

Comment: RIGHT JOIN?!? That makes sense only if you have order_items that don't belongs to an order. (Think `main table left join optional data`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the code you actually need to do your query is already there, you just need to reword it a bit, and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    so.customer_id,
    SUM(soi.quantity*soi.list_price) AS [ITEM SALES],
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(so.order_date) = 2016
             THEN soi.quantity*soi.list_price ELSE 0 END) AS [TOTAL SALES 2016]
FROM sales.orders AS so
LEFT JOIN sales.order_items AS soi
    ON so.order_id = soi.order_id
GROUP BY
    so.customer_id
ORDER BY
    so.customer_id;
```

Comment: You should introduce table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.

Comment: @Gordon I generally agree with you, but wanted to stick as closely as possible to the OP's original attempt for learning purposes.